# SQL Max and Min for complex conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

T1 for instance

```
University_ID || Country_ID |
-----------------------------
20            || 2          | 
30            || 1          |
40            || 3          |
45            || 1          | 
50            || 2          |
65            || 1          |
-----------------------------
```

While t2 for instance

```
Competition_ID || First_University || Second_University || First_score || Second_score ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              || 30               || 45                || 10          || 12           ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2              || 20               || 50                || 5           || 5            ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13             || 65               || 45                || 10          || 10           ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5              || 30               || 65                || 3           || 15           ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
42             || 45               || 65                || 8           || 4            ||
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

** Here, the first_university & the second university columns in t2 are equal to university_Id in t1.

** And Each country has more than one university.

** Competition_ID is unique

Now, we need to calculate >> the winner university (who has the max score in all competitions) per each country (group by country)

And >> In case  two university from the same country are equal, bring the one who has the lowest ID (University_ID )

The query should return

```
-------------------------
Country_id || winner_id |
----------------------
1         || 45         |
2         || 20         |
3         || 40         |
-------------------------
```

Comment: How can I get those expected results, when your example data has no `Country_id` = `3`

Comment: the data here is just a piece of the data -even results- for example, Jerry. I just want to know how too reach the result.

Comment: I understand that but it would be helpful for us to have _more_ data so we can test our solutions with a demonstration for you. There is no way, with what you have given us, for us to produce your expected result. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I joined the tables >>> From t1 Inner Join t1 On University_ID IN (First_University , Second_University)
but I don't how to sum all the results for each university and then get the university that has the max results per each country. if you can help.

Comment: How about now, Jerry?

Comment: Almost done...@Nash

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your effort, I'm waiting for you, Jerry.

Comment: I posted my solution @Nash

Comment: Did it work? Did you try the demo? @Nash

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerry for your effort. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with 
  univ_scores as (
    select first_university univ, first_score score from t2
    union all
    select second_university, second_score from t2
  ),
  totals as (
    select univ, sum(score) total
    from univ_scores
    group by univ
  ),
  cte as (
    select t1.country_id, t1.university_id,
      row_number() over (partition by t1.country_id order by t.total desc, univ) rn
    from t1 left join totals t
    on t.univ = t1.university_id
  )  
select country_id, university_id
from cte
where rn = 1
```

The 1st and second CTEs calculate the total score for each university and the 3d ranks all universities inside the country they belong according to your conditions.
Finally the query returns the top ranked universities for each country.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4U6F3SwcBewv3LjT1YRdnQ/1).
Results:

```
| country_id | university_id |
| ---------- | ------------- |
| 1          | 45            |
| 2          | 20            |
| 3          | 40            |
```

Comment: Forbas, I always learn from you.

Thank you very much for your help, time and effort.

Comment: No dear, it's right. no doubt. I just came up with a new solution. I'd love your thoughts about, forpas.

Answer (score 0):

With the data that you gave me, the following query achieves the proper results:

```
WITH
    winners AS (

        SELECT
            Competition_ID,
            CASE
                WHEN (MAX(First_score) OVER (PARTITION BY Competition_ID)) > (MAX(Second_score) OVER (PARTITION BY Competition_ID)) THEN First_University
                WHEN (MAX(First_score) OVER (PARTITION BY Competition_ID)) < (MAX(Second_score) OVER (PARTITION BY Competition_ID)) THEN Second_University
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN First_University > Second_University THEN Second_University ELSE First_University END
                END AS Winner

        FROM
            T2

        GROUP BY
            Competition_ID,
             First_score,
             Second_score,
             First_University,
             Second_University

    ),

    scores AS (

        SELECT
            w.Competition_ID,
            w.Winner,
            CASE
                WHEN T2.First_score > T2.Second_score THEN T2.First_score
                WHEN T2.First_score < T2.Second_score THEN T2.Second_score
                ELSE T2.First_score
            END AS Score

        FROM
            winners w
                INNER JOIN T2 ON w.Competition_ID = T2.Competition_ID AND (w.Winner = T2.First_University OR w.Winner = T2.Second_University)

    ),

    countries AS (
        SELECT
            T1.Country_ID,
            s.Winner,
            s.Score

        FROM
            scores s
                INNER JOIN T1 ON s.Winner = T1.University_ID

    ),

    highest AS (

        SELECT
            c.Country_ID AS Country_ID,
            MAX(c.Score) AS score

        FROM
            countries c

        GROUP BY
            c.Country_ID

    )

    SELECT
        h.Country_ID,
        c.Winner

    FROM
        highest h INNER JOIN countries c ON h.Country_ID = c.Country_ID AND h.score = c.Score
```

You can see a demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ccf66/3

Here is the DDL I used:

```
CREATE TABLE T2
    (Competition_ID int, First_University int, Second_University int, First_score int, Second_score int)
;

INSERT INTO T2
    (Competition_ID, First_University, Second_University, First_score, Second_score)
VALUES
    (1, 30, 45, 10, 12),
    (2, 20, 50, 5, 5),
    (13, 65, 45, 10, 10),
    (5, 30, 65, 3, 15),
    (42, 45, 65, 8, 4)
;

CREATE TABLE T1
    (University_ID int, Country_ID int)
;

INSERT INTO T1
    (University_ID, Country_ID)
VALUES
    (20, 2),
    (30, 1),
    (40, 3),
    (45, 1),
    (50, 2),
    (65, 1)
;
```

Comment: What a great effort you gave to help me, Jerry. 
But unfortunately the results are not right. 
But really thanks a lot dear for your valuable time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have another Solution, too

```
WITH
Data AS (
    SELECT  t1.University_ID,
    t1.Country_ID,
    SUM (CASE   WHEN    t2.First_Score = t2.Second_Score
         THEN   1
         WHEN   (t1.University_ID = t2.First_University
                 AND
                 t2.First_Score > t2.Second_Score)
         OR     (t1.University_ID = t2.Second_University
                 AND
                 t2.Second_Score > t2.First_Score)
         THEN   3
         ELSE   0
         END)   AS  Score
    FROM    t1
    LEFT JOIN
    t2
    ON
    University_ID
    IN
    (First_University, Second_University)
    GROUP BY            t1.University_ID,
    t1.Country_ID),

CTE AS  (
    SELECT  *,
    ROW_NUMBER ()   OVER (PARTITION BY  Country_ID
                          ORDER BY      Score   DESC)       AS RN
    FROM    Data)

SELECT      Country_ID      AS  Country_ID,
University_ID   AS  Winner_ID
FROM        CTE
WHERE   RN = 1
```

demo
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGv4T6pYtrq5pV7oZNvCCm/4

Comment: In this solution you solve a different requirement than the one in your question because you are summing points (3, 1, 0) and not scores, right?

Comment: I'll explain it to you Muhammad. It's a conditional sum, here. why? because you need only to sum the points of each University ID when it's a winner in each Competition ID and ignore it when it's a loser in any given match. OK?. To calculate this conditional aggregation I converted the scores into points. Here, we need only to retrieve who's the winner (university) with the highest score per each  country. I hope it's clear now, dear.

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me by going exactly by the information provided, I framed this query and it should work.

```
SELECT 
    b.Country_ID, 
    b.University_ID AS Winner_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.Country_ID, a.University_ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Country_ID ORDER BY a.score DESC, a.University_ID ASC) AS rank_per_country
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            z.Country_ID, y.University_ID, y.score
        FROM 
            T1 z
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                x.University_ID, SUM(x.score) AS score
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    First_University AS University_ID,
                    First_score AS score
                FROM 
                    T2 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 
                    Second_University AS University_ID,
                    Second_score AS score
                FROM 
                    T2 
            ) x
            GROUP BY x.University_ID
        ) y
        ON (z.University_ID = y.University_ID)
    ) a 
) b
WHERE 
    b.rank_per_country = 1;
```

The innermost queries (`table x`) are to extract `University_ID` and their `total scores` in all the competitions.

Logical `table x` has been joined with `T1` to get respective `Country_ID`s and represented as logical `table a`.

Next, I applied `ROW_NUMBER` to sort the records by `score` and if scores are same, then sort by ascending `University_ID`s.

In `table b`, I'm just selecting the final result for the output.

[image]

Here is the SQL Fiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ccf66/5).

Comment: So mean, my query is giving the right result, unlike yours which is giving wrong result for country_id = 1.

SQL Fiddle for your reference. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5ccf66/5

Comment: @Nash, please go to the SQL Fiddle link and verify.

Comment: Kumar, first of all thank you very much for the great effort and time to help me. the results look correct. but where's the 3rd university ?

Comment: @Nash, when I replied to your question, there isn't any record for `Universisty_ID = 40` (which is in `Country_ID = 3`) in `T2` table. This was also pointed out by Jerry M is first comment on the question. Therefore, it's not coming in the output I shared. If you see the SQL Fiddle link I shared, there is no entry in table `T2` where `University_ID = 40`. If you add, this entry to the table `T2`, you will get result for `Country_ID=3` also.

Comment: I'm glad! If my solution solves your problem, feel free to upvote or mark answer as correct. Cheers! :)

Comment: Please click on the tick mark on top of my answer to mark it as correct answer. :)

Comment: Do you know why it will never produce the 3rd country? because of the inner join. First of all it must be a Left join. and then we must make it retrieve the score instead of null.